# Why does installing jre1.7.0 give me no alternatives?

Tags: java

Did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java 1
```

Then:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

But I get:

```
There is only one alternative in link group java (providing /usr/bin/java): /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.7.0/bin/java
Nothing to configure.
```

And

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I followed [How can I install Sun-Oracles proprietary Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

Comment: The most up-to-date guide for installing Java on Ubuntu are: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Answer (score 1):

I think my friend gave me the wrong version of Ubuntu. Using the 64bit jre now gives me:

```
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
```